# java build path problems

Tags: java, eclipse

From someone's project, I am getting this error:

```
Java Build Path Problems (1 item)
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5.  There are no JREs installed in the workplace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

I have the latest JDK (jdk1.6.0_25).  From my understanding, I can do one of the following:

1. Download the J2SE-1.5 environment to match the project.
2. Edit the project to agree with the latest JDK.  **How can I do this?**

Comment: Download the J2SE-1.5 environment due to prevent situation, when you will use new classes from newer jre, which in 1.5 was absent. This is a solution.

Comment: four things are to be done, look http://stackoverflow.com/a/20692572/715269

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a good discussion on this:

- [How to use JDK 1.6 in 1.5 compliance mode](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-use-JDK-1-6-in-1-5-compliance-mode-td379199.html)

Basically you should

1. Download and install the 1.5 JDK. ([download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html))
2. In Eclipse, Go to *Window* → *Preferences* → *Java* → *Installed JREs*.
3. Add the 1.5 JDK to the list.
4. Select 1.5 as *Compiler Compliance Level*.

Answer (score 53):

1. Right click on project, Properties, Java Build Path.
2. Remove the current JRE library.
3. Click Add library > JRE System Library > Workspace default JRE.

Comment: much much easier for macosx users. thx

Comment: Works properly on Windows too.

Comment: And after updating the Maven project the JRE 1.5 is back again. WITH JRE 1.7. (in pom compiler is set to 1.7)

Answer (score 14):

Go for the second option, Edit the project to agree with the latest JDK

- Right click "**JRE System Library [J2SE 1.5]** in your project"
- Choose "**Properties**"
- Select "**Workspace default JRE (jdk1.6**)

[image]

Comment: Don't need to remove anything for this configuration. It is simple :)

Comment: But doesn't work. ;-(

Answer (score 4):

From the Package Explorer in Eclipse, you can right click the project, choose Build Path, Configure Build Path to get the build path dialog. From there you can remove the JRE reference for the 1.5 JRE and 'Add Library' to add a reference to your installed JRE.

Answer (score 3):

To configure your JRE in eclipse:

- Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs...
- Click Add
- Find the directory of your JDK > Click OK

Answer (score 1):

Try this too in addition to MahmoudS comments. 
Change the maven compiler source and target in your pom.xml to the java version which you are using. Say 1.7 for jdk7

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```