# Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

In building eclipse code, I have this "Build path specifies ..." error.

[image]

`Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.`

Googling to find this post : [java build path problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077572/java-build-path-problems) to add J2SE-1.4 execution environments.

[image]

And checked Java SE 7 is installed correctly.

[image]

However, I still get the error. What might be wrong?

I have this information with `java -version` in my command line.

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you show the value of `java -version`?

Comment: Is this project specific (or) overall eclipse settings? I would check both.

Comment: @Nambari: The setup is using Preference in eclipse menu, so it's for overall eclipse setup.

Comment: Check BuildPath menu above screenshot. It seems it is having some references to 1.4.

Comment: @Nambari: Could you elaborate? I don't see BuildPath menu in the Preferences.

Comment: Observer screenshot in question-->Under Java--> 4 items top of "Installed JREs", there is Build Path. Expand that, go to lib tab--> It seems there is some references to java 1.4

Comment: You need to uncheck JRE (J2SE1.4), then delete 1.4 and do Add Library---> Select Java 7 you have on your machine.

Comment: @Nambari: Thanks for your help, bhuang3's solution works fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to go to `Project|Properties`, then Choose the `Java Build Path`, 
chose the current `JRE System Library`, and choose Remove.

Select `Add Library`, and under the `JRE System Library category`, select your system library;
try to choose the `Workspace default JRE`

Comment: I have the same issue with other projects. Instead of setting for all of them one by one, is there an setup for all the projects?

Comment: This only temporarily fixes the problem. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4

Answer (score 0):

You can try going into Preference|Java|Installed JREs. Click on Add... button. "Add JRE" page opens and select-Standard VM. On "Add JRE" page, next to "JRE Home",click on button "Directory". Under page "Browse for folder", find Program Files-> Java and find folder with JRE version e.g if the message said JRE 1.6 missing add the folder location JRE 1.6 in it like -> C:\Prgram Files\Java\jdk1.6_30